# AWS cli - what timezone it uses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

After running token generator - I get this output:

```
token_expiration = 2019-02-15T17:07:49Z
```

What time zone it is and how to convert it to EST?

Thanks

Comment: Z means UTC. It's historically called "Zulu time" in military operations...

Answer (score 2):

The end Z indicates it is UTC. To convert from UTC to EST you can use this function:

```
$date = new DateTime('2019-02-15T17:07:49Z', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Asuming this question was PHP

Comment: Presumably you don't need to provide the UTC timezone parameter to the DateTime constructor when the time itself indicates Zulu time.